# Legend navigation animation in highcharts for any graph

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, legend, redraw

how to redraw a particular series when clicked on a legend in highcharts
with using legengItemClick method modification without updating the series.

Comment: What animation do you want to happen?  When hiding and showing a series changes the extremes, the animation fires off for me.  See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked and click on Asia in the legend

Comment: Here I have observed that animation is happening when the scale on Y axis or X axis changed. That helps a little bit but, [lineChart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/animation-none/), see this one. Here I need animation when the legend is clicked.

Comment: Beining honest its unclear, when you click update, point is updated. Do you mean that animation should be smooth? When you click on the legend item, how it should be animated, smooth from left to right (like in init) ?